# Triggering Azure alert action group from runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-automation, alerts, azure-log-analytics

Currently we are triggering alerts directly from runbook by using sendgrid, instead we want to move all alerts to LA and trigger from one place so that in future we may use alert suppression logics.

objective is we want to trigger azure alert action group from runbook directly, is there a way to do that?

Comment: em, why need to use runbook if you choose log analytics?

Comment: we are checking VPN gateway connection status every 2 mins via runbook and triggering mail using sendgrid from runbook directly, if we create alert via LA, its taking 2-3 mins for data to be available in workspace, so this will delay on alerting to avoid that checking provision to trigger action group directly so that i dont need to mention any emails in script and all taken care by azure

Comment: @DevReddyIn this case azure send grid needs to whitelist some of the parameters